# Adding a dependency for a target in automake

Tags: automake

I've run into a problem with automake that I can't seem to find a clean solution for, which seem like it should be possible (even simple), but nothing simple works.

Basically the problem I have is with a source file that includes an autogenerated header file.  I can add the dependencies to generate the header file just file, and once the header exists, everything works, as automake's auto dependency generation takes care of everything.  The problem is the *first* time you run make in a clean tree, the dependency files don't exist, so automake doesn't know to generate the header file, which makes the compile of the file including the header fail without generating any dependencies.  Its a chicken-and-egg problem -- you need to manually tell (auto)make to build the header file.

The obvious solution is just to add a dependency to the Makefile.am file for the header, but that doesn't work, since having a dependency for a target override automake's automatic rule generation, as the docs say:

> Note that Automake does not make any distinction between rules with commands and rules that only specify dependencies. So it is not possible to append new dependencies to an automake-defined target without redefining the entire rule.

For now I've hacked around the problem by 'hiding' the dependency from automake, but this only works for GNU-make:

Makefile.am:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = foo
foo_SOURCES = main.c foobar.c baz.c

gen.h: system.spec
        ...command to regen gen.h

# foobar.c #includes gen.h, so it needs to exist prior to compiling foobar.c
$(eval foo-foobar.o: gen.h)
```

This does the trick, but seems ugly.  Is there a better automake-safe way of doing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Automake supplies `BUILT_SOURCES` to solve this problem.  Files added to this are built before ordinary compilations are done -- it is specifically intended for generated headers and sources.

In your case this should suffice:

```
BUILT_SOURCES = gen.h
```

Comment: This seems generally safer than the GNUmake specific eval, though it has the problem that it doesn't allow building specific targets, just `make all`

Comment: Here's a link to Automake's documentation for `BUILT_SOURCES`: http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Sources.html

Comment: besides BUILT_SOURCES, you may need nodist_<your_code_n>_SOURCES, CLEANFILES and a dependency on how to make the BUILT_SOURCES file.  nodist_<your_code_n>_SOURCES means your source code need to include a file which  is not present and needed to be generated during the make process. CLEANFILES  means the generated file will be cleaned by 'make clean'

Answer (score 0):

sample Makefile.am should be like

```
bin_PROGRAMS = foo
foo_SOURCES = main.c foobar.c baz.c
nodist_foo_SOURCES = gen.h
BUILT_SOURCES = gen.h
CLEANFILES = gen.h
gen.h: Makefile system.spec
    command to regen gen.h 
#above line should begin with a <TAB>
```